# Regular expressions matching strings that don't start with `A` or whitespace

Tags: regex

I want my regular expression to match strings that don't start with the letter `A` or whitespaces.
I've tried `^-|^(^(\W|A).)`, but it doesn't work, any ideas why?

Comment: Why the rule about the dash? That character is included in the "neither a space nor an `A`" rule, so it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 25):

> regular expression doesn't start with character A or whitespace

```
^(?![A\s])
```

To match the whole string, you need to add `.*`

```
^(?![A\s]).*
```

OR

```
^[^A\s].*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vD9cD7/1)

Strings don't start with `A` or `Space` will match also the strings starts with hyphen `-`, so you don't need to specify the pattern for strings starting with hyphen.

Answer (score 14):

You were close:

```
^[^ A]
```

- `[^ A]` matches anything other than `A` or space
- `^` anchors the regex at start of the string

[**Regex Example**](http://regex101.com/r/eI6aL6/3)

Comment: `^(-|[^ A]) = ^([^ A])`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hehe :D Oops